# PHP clear up Array preg_grep

Tags: php, html, arrays, preg-match, preg-grep

I have currently a problem with arrays in php,
i requested all `<li>` tags from an html site with:

```
$dochtml = new DOMDocument();
$dochtml -> loadHTMLFile("my.html");

/*get all li’s*/
$lis = $dochtml -> getElementsByTagName('li');
```

My Html Body:

```
<li>gfvgvefg</li>
<li>ferfergegeg</li>
<li id="vdfvdfvf"></li>
<li id="id_1"> My Value 1</li>
<li id="id_2"> My Value 2</li>
<li id="id_3"> My Value 3</li>
<li id="id_4"> My Value 4</li>
<li></li>
<li id="efgvefgvfg">gfegvefgbv</li>
```

then i echo all id’s and values from my `<li>` tags:

```
    foreach($lis as $key) {

        $id = $key -> getAttribute('id');
        $value = $key -> nodeValue;

        echo $id. ' - '.$value.'<br>';

    }
```

Output:

```
0 - gfvgvefg
0 - ferfergegeg
vdfvdfvf - 0
id_1 - My Value 1
id_2 - My Value 2
id_3 - My Value 3
id_4 - My Value 4 
0 - 0
efgvefgvfg - gfegvefgbv
```

You see some id’s are 0, and values too.

What i want is this Output (print_r):

```
Array ( [id_1] => My Value 1
     [id_2] => My Value 2
     [id_3] => My Value 3
    [id_4] => My Value 4)
```

So only the id’s with id_* and the correct Value, in an array.

I try this:

```
foreach($lis as $key) {
    // gets, and outputs the ID and content of each DIV
    $id = $key -> getAttribute('id');
    $value = $key -> nodeValue;

    //echo $id. ' - '.$value.'<br>';


    $array = array($value => $id);
    $matches  = preg_grep('/^id_(\w+)/i', $array);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

but i get this output (print_r):

```
Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( )
```

no id no value, nothing.
I know i can use array_keys by preg_grep, but then i get only the id’s and the empty arrays…

Here is the code in an online compile, for better understanding.

[Code Online Compiled](https://eval.in/788861)

Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do everything in a single `foreach`:

```
$arrLis = array();
foreach($lis as $key) {

    $id = $key -> getAttribute('id');

    // check if `id` starts with `id_` string
    if (strpos($id, 'id_') === 0) {
        $value = $key -> nodeValue;

        echo $id. ' - '.$value.'<br>';

        $arrLis[$id] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($arrLis);
```

Comment: Okay cool now my Output is `Array ( [id_1] => My Value 1 [id_2] => My Value 2 [id_3] => My Value 3 [id_4] => My Value 4 [efgvefgvfg] => gfegvefgbv )` but how i implement the preg_grep function now to get only `Array ( [id_1] => My Value 1 [id_2] => My Value 2 [id_3] => My Value 3 [id_4] => My Value 4 )`.... Wildcard: id_*

Comment: Hey very cool Thanks !! One more question, is strpos better as preg_grep ?

Comment: In your case it is. Because with `strpos` you do just __one__ action - check a string for a substring, and with `preg_grep` you do several - create array, then run `preg_grep`, which under the hood will iterate over array. So why do several actions instead of one?

Answer (score 1):

The same using XPath:

```
$dom =new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile("my.html");
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodeList = $xp->query('//li[starts-with(@id, "id_")]');

foreach ($nodeList as $node) {
    $result[$node->getAttribute('id')] = $node->nodeValue;
}

print_r($result);
```